# proper trigger to add some custom behavior on form validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to add some custom logic in my MVC5 project to change the behavior of unobtrusive javascript client side validation of text input. By change I mean I'd like to be able to apply bootstrap style including glyphicons dynamically.

I know it can be done by manipulating `DOM` - applying and removing appropriate classes (like 'has-success' etc.). Yet I don't know in what event I could handle this not to override default behavior applied in `jquery.validate.*`. The best situation would be if I could recognize a bad format in runtime (so let's say the user is to write number, but he's just pressed "s"), not just after button submit. I could do it quite easily by checking HTML5 attributes used for validating, but I don't know when I could do that.

I've tried on do it in `document.ready()`, but submitting a button doesn't make this event to trigger if there are errors(corresponding `ActionResult` is not called), and- that's the point I would even want it to trigger.

Any ideas what event would be appriopriate? I don't want any additional jQuery plugins etc., I'd like the behavior it is now I just need to make some changes and I need to know where I can do that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery's .change() function.

```
$( ".target" ).change(function() {
  _yourcodehere_
});
```

Itt fill fire whenever the selected input's value changes